# Unable to get accessibility event information from Wordpad.exe

Tags: windows, windows-7, ms-office, accessibility, wordpad

[image]

[image]

I am trying to capture windows accessibility events from `wordpad.exe` for context menu items shown above. When I look at the `OBJ_FOCUS` events from `AccEvent.exe`, it doesn't show me anything but

> "Error: getting object: hr=0xFFFFFFFF80004005 - Unspecified error".

Sometimes it'll show the same thing except it'll say "`Access denied`" instead of unspecified error.

I am not sure why this is happening because I can see the events fine all the other Microsoft office products. I am using `Windows 7` on a `VM`.

If anybody have any ideas about this, please let me know.

Thank you.